# AngularJS sync live collection with REST and get live updates

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, websocket

I am looking for some best practice how to synchronize collections with REST and get live updates with web sockets. If I have a collection `items`...

- `{id: 1, title: "First todo", completed: false}`
- `{id: 2, title: "Second todo", completed: true}`
- `{id: 3, title: "Third todo", completed: false}`

I am defining a REST resource for the TodoItems:

```
app.factory('TodoItems', function($resource) {
    return $resource( '/todoitems/:id', { id: '@id' },
            {create: { method: 'POST' },
            update: { method: 'PUT' } }
});
```

The rest resource should be used to `fetch` the whole list but `update` only individual items.

and I could probably have some kind of a `webSocket.listenForChanges(item.id, cb)`.

Having those two ways to fetch, manipulate data and get live updates, how do I actually put it to use?

... I could do `$scope.$watchCollection` and get updates whenever whatever changes but then the callback will run everytime I manually change the collection, not only due to user updates as user updates need to run `TodoItems.update(item)` and web socket updates must not trigger my REST API.

```
webSocket.listenForChanges(item.id, function(newItem) { $scope.item = newItem; });
// This triggers $watchCollection - NOT GOOD, because $watchCollection
// could trigger and call upon REST
```

AngularFire somehow does it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7ZI7z7qnHU#t=30m28s but I suspect they do it by bulk synchronization of whole array.

A little modification would be to `$watch` individual items in each item's controller, having the following JADE template

```
ul
  li(ng-repeat='todo in todos',ng-controller='TodoItemController')
```

The problem is however the same, the `$watch` cannot differentiate server updates from user updates.

Is my only hope to call my REST API only from the scope controls like `updateItem(item)` `removeItem(item)` or is there some more clever way to automate synchronization of collections over REST/websocket?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ngChange to watch for user changes.  Per the documentation it states ngChange will "Evaluate given expression when user changes the input. The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model."

I am curious why you're mixing a REST API and a WebSocket API.  Why not do it all through WebSockets?  It's lighter weight and it seems like it would be less confusing to not mix protocols.

Comment: Semantically REST API is very sane so basing the WebSocket API on REST API makes sense and for free I get a fallback for lightweight REST clients. Thanks for the answer, when I process your suggestion I will give some feedback!

Comment: The REST API would make GET/POST/PUT types of HTTP URL requests and the server API (typically) uses the request header to interpret the action.  This is very different from WebSockets which only uses the URL to create a connection, then subsequently sends only messages and no longer sends GET/POST/PUT URL requests.  Your WebSocket messages would need to specify an action since there is no request header to interpret.  I suppose if you always passed JSON data they could be similar, but then I wouldn't call it a REST API.

Comment: Indeed, REST-alike API would be a better name. I am posting action in JSON messages as well as providing a scheme for a response matching a given request.

Comment: Have lots of other stuff to work on but gonna back to that problem when things settle. :) Thanks.